# What was Europa Report's budget?

Tags: production, europa-report

Most reviews of [*Europa Report* (2013)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2051879/) state that it was made on a low budget. But what was its budget exactly? Neither IMDb nor Wikipedia carry this information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only site i got is [articles.latimes.com](http://articles.latimes.com/2013/aug/01/entertainment/la-et-mn-europa-report-20130802), which says Europa Report's budget is less than $10 million.